# What is the suffix in indexed math symbols

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes, mathematics, science

I've been watching some online courses and I'm having a difficulty understanding what exactly are they saying. The courses are scientific in nature and rather often an indexed symbols appear. The indexed symbols are usually written with a subscript, like this:

[image]

When refering to those, the instructor pronounced them like you would pronounce "ace of n" and "eyes of c". It seems that the suffix ***s*** is added to the letter.
I have completed a non-English education, so this was new to me.

What are the rules regarding indexed symbols?

Is it simply: a's of n, or i's of c, and more importantly **why**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mishearing the instructor. He is saying "a sub n" and "i sub c", where "sub" is short for "subscript".

If the symbols are written with a superscript, like a<sup>n</sup> and I<sup>c</sup>, then the spoken version is "a sup n" and "i sup c", where "sup" is pronounced like "soup", and is short for "superscript".

Comment: "Ace of n" ... I like that interpretation.

Comment: I agree that it appears that you have misheard the speaker, possibly due to accent. And the abbreviation of subscript is likely why you misunderstood.

Comment: Now that you've told me, I can really hear "sub"... Fascinating! :) Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Notice that the plural suffix is pronounced /z/ in many cases (depending on what it follows), whereas _sub_ always starts with /s/. Learning which words spelled with "S" are pronounced /z/ and which are pronounced /s/ is basic to learning English. Only the whole sentence can tell you, at times.